# Does Windows store some counter between restarts?

Tags: windows

i wonder if Windows OS (let's say win10) stores and manages some value(s) of this properties:

- managed by OS so update is done by system internals , not to be messed by user
- it is increased between restarts/reboots, everytime a restart os I get new value which is greater then previous, like db sequence
- can be relativly easy read by common api like (file, registers, etc).

Comment: Maybe this other [answer](https://superuser.com/a/298023) in SuperUser may help? I don't have a Windows by hand to check it but it may help you.